# how can be switch from prefork to worker MPM in running apache on solaris10

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris, solaris-10, mpm-worker

bash-3.00# /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
bash-3.00#

bash-3.00# /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.0.63
Server built:   Feb 10 2008 04:45:11
bash-3.00#

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you have a worker MPM httpd binary compiled or not. Some distributions come with several binaries (named `httpd.worker` or such like) and you just change your start-up script to point at the desired binary.

On the other hand you may have to compile Apache yourself with the desired MPM.

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache has SMF "start scripts" see this howto: http://wikis.sun.com/display/WebStack/Web+Stack+Getting+Started+Guide#WebStackGettingStartedGuide-UsingSMFtoManageServices

Comment: thanks but this is not working for me as apache is not using SMF

Comment: bash-3.00# ps -aef | grep http
    root 26225     1   0 14:03:00 ?           0:03 /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
webservd 28095 26225   0 14:44:50 ?           0:02 /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
webservd 28096 26225   0 14:44:50 ?           0:02 /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
    root 28335 26102   0 16:36:39 pts/1       0:00 grep http
webservd 28073 26225   0 14:44:50 ?           0:02 /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
webservd 28079 26225   0 14:44:50 ?           0:02 /usr/apache2/bin/httpd -k start